# Using the Comparable interface when comparing Strings

Tags: java, arrays, interface, comparator, comparable

I searched for this question, but I only found one thread that was kind of confusing, so I'm going to ask here for what I hope will be a clearer answer.

I have an assignment to use the Comparable interface to sort objects in an array by customer name. I have only done this with integers so far, so I'm not sure how to compare the strings together. How would I go about that? Here is where I am so far, assuming I am to use a.name compared to this.name:

```
public int comparedTo(Customer a)
{

}   //end comparedTo
```

I also need to make a class to implement the Comparator interface to sort the values based on customer purchases and I think I did that properly, but I'd like to make sure before I go ripping my hair out when it's wrong. Here is what I did for that:

```
class NameComparator implements Comparator{
public int compare(Object cust1, Object cust2){    

    String cust1Purch = ((Customer)cust1).purchase;        
    String cust2Purch = ((Customer)cust2).purchase;

    return cust1Purch.compareTo(cust2Purch);
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Its all ok, but you can specify Comparator generic type and then no need to cast objects:

```
class NameComparator implements Comparator<Customer>{
public int compare(Customer cust1, Customer cust2){    

    String cust1Purch = cust1.purchase;        
    String cust2Purch = cust2.purchase;

    return cust1Purch.compareTo(cust2Purch);
}
```

Comment: That has been changed! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here is a complete example that might help you:

A `CustomerComparator`:

```
class CustomerComparator implements Comparator<Customer> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Customer c1, Customer c2) {
        return c1.name.compareTo(c2.name);   // or, simply c1.compareTo(c2);
    }
}
```

A `Comparable` `Customer`:

```
class Customer implements Comparable<Customer> {

    String name;

    public Customer(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Customer o) {
        return name.compareTo(o.name);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

A simple test driver:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Customer> customers = Arrays.asList(new Customer("Bravo"),
                                                 new Customer("Charlie"),
                                                 new Customer("Delta"),
                                                 new Customer("Alpha"));
        Collections.sort(customers);

        // Or
        // Collections.sort(customers, new CustomerComparator());

        System.out.println(customers);

    }
}
```

([ideone.com demo](http://ideone.com/E4lh6))

Comment: Why would it be Collections.sort()? I was under the impression that the sort was called via Arrays.sort().

Comment: `Collections.sort` are for lists etc. `Arrays.sort()` are for arrays. You can use either one really.

Comment: Ohh, okay. That sounds familiar. I probably should have realized that, but I'm too focused on this assignment. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine. But you can utilize Generics:

```
class NameComparator implements Comparator<Customer> {
    public int compare(Customer cust1, Customer cust2) {..}
}
```

Comment: So rather than have it as String cust1Purch = ((Customer)cust1).purchase;, I would have it say String cust1Purch = cust1.purchase; ? Just double checking.

Comment: @Lish - yup. Casting would be redundant.

Comment: @Yanick Rochon well, yeah, but the programmer wouldn't need to cast.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to get it right for the `Comparable` interface. Nothing really complicated there.

As for the `Comparator`, if you're not using generics, you also need to validate both argument for the same base type, at least `Comparable` since you're using that interface :

```
if (cust1 instanceof Comparable && cust2 instanceof Comparable) {
   Comparable c1 = (Comparable) cust1;
   Comparable c2 = (Comparable) cust2;
   return c1.compareTo(c2);
} else {
   return false;
}
```

Comment: My problem is that I'm not sure how to compare the strings in the comparedTo() method. Any insight?

Comment: if you look at the `String` class, it already implements the `Comparable` interface :)

Comment: I saw that once I refreshed and someone else had said that. This site moves FAST! :)

Answer (score 0):

1) I would use generics to define your comparator and avoid additinal class casting:

```
class NameComparator implements Comparator<Customer> {
    public int compare(Customer cust1, Customer cust2) {
      ...
    }
}
```

2) String class in java already implements Comparable interface ( http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html ). So, if you need to just compare on customer's name or purchase string, then you can just delegate it to String and that's what you already do.